# Real time web application

Tags: comet, real-time

I really need your help with this. We are planning on developing a real-time web application. We look at different libraries and concepts and a little confused. 
What we need is: clients connect to websites and send data(usually an integer + client machine name) whenever they want (usually 1-5 seconds). Also, the same clients must receive data(the data received from other clients) from the server in a real-time mode. (maximum 0.5 seconds). Also, this data must be stored in the database.

We were thinking about using different technologies, but cannot decide which one to use. 
We need this web application to be supported on Iphones and Android Phones (maybe blackberry).
and, of course desktop browsers.

Pooling seems not a very good Idea in this situation, due to highloads.

Html 5 web sockets kinda new, and probably not supported by all browsers.

Have anyone used nodejs ? 
or twisted matrix: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/? 
or orbited(cannot post more than one link)?
or tornado?
Or XMPP(Jabber. I did not find good examples.)?
or something else?

What technology is the best to use in this type of project? Also, we would probably prefer the technology that has some community support and free to use.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of things to consider here.  I would say that HTML 5 is not an option, simply due to support across platform.

Running with NodeJS is most likely possible, but the communication methods are really complicated.  Pushing data to a page isn't really something that HTML/web apps are designed to do....

To get a valid answer you are going to need to get someone to come in and sit with you to really iron out details and implementation.

Comment: Agreed, and don't mix up application layer protocols (HTTP, XMPP, etc) with their implementations (TwistedWeb, NodeJS, Tornado).

Comment: Yeah, I know that I mixed up a little bit. I know that web apps are note designed to do so. I know all the details of the project. It looks fairly simple, if we will find an appropriate technology.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data? What is the purpose?

For real-time you're not going to get a web site unless you use some type of RIA but even then, it isn't going to be enough. Services aren't going to be good enough either. You're going to end up doing some type of polling which will only ever be psuedo-real-time unless you do duplex mode which wont be supported on most of the platforms you want to support.

sockets are the way to go but that requires a client for each platform you want to handle. Maybe you should rethink your requirements.

Comment: Data: integers, just digits. purpose: it is like a very fast auction. Somebody set price for an item, and other people bid. It should be very very fast (read real-time)

Comment: pseudo-real-time is fine with me. Who cares how it is called. So there is no other choice other than pooling? what about different protocol like: XMPP. is it a standard yet?

Comment: still going to end up using sockets (real-time) or polling (pseudo-real-time). You will need to be able to either keep a connection open (made from the client) which both client/server can send data or the client has to send pings to see if there is anything it needs to get from the server. You have to consider security, you can't send data to a client. If it were just mobile, I would say use the push infrastructure (i know WP7 has it, dunno about android or iPhone). Keeping sockets open across internet isn't smart idea and might not be supported by mobile devices. Polling is safest.

Comment: Thanksa lot we are looking into http://www.ape-project.org/ or XMPP protocol right now

Comment: ape-project looks like the way to go. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that clients "connect to a website", do you really need it to be a website? It sounds like all the client is sending is a number and for that you don't need a website. Just pick the language of your choice, open up a socket, and go from there.

Are you streaming data to be visualized? You might want to take a look at [graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com) (and/or "pyped" which is part of graphite).

Comment: But what is the other way other than web application? We do not want anyone to install anything on their devices. But still we need web application for administrator.

Comment: @user194076: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you need an administrative interface you'll need a web server for that, but for the server that accepts and delivers data in real time you don't need a web server. A web server is just one of many, many kinds of servers you can run, and if all you're doing is sending numbers and client names back and forth you don't need the overhead of a web server for that.